# How to see this step in deriving an equality in Fourier series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

(Previous steps are omitted.)

By convergence of Fourier series, we have
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^2}(-1)^n=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Then how come we can get this from the above formula:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the $n^{th}$ term of the series is zero for even $n$, so you can replace $n$ by $2n-1$ (which gives you all the odd values):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{\pi (2n-1)^2}(-1)^{(2n-1)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

And because $(-1)^{(2n-1)}=-1$, multiplying both sides by $\pi/2$ gives the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^2}(-1)^n=
\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n\text{ odd}}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi n^2}=
\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
Simplifying,
$$
\sum_{n\text{ odd}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\implies 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.
$$